# Advice for repeating a loop for Simon Says game in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a Simon Says game to improve my programming skills, it is harder than I thought it would be. So initially I have decided there will be 50 levels max, so I generate 50 random numbers between 1-4 and store them in an array, i tested this works in the console:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <50; i++){
        random = randomGenerator.nextInt(4)+1;
        array[i] = random;
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(i)+" " + Integer.toString(array[i]));  
    }
```

Next I call a method called play which should run the game, in this method I have  for loop which runs 50 times, it checks if index i of my array is 1, 2, 3 or 4 then colours the numbered button.

```
public void play(){

    for(int i =ii; i<50; i++){
        if(b1bool==false){
            if(array[i] == 1){
                //Set button to Blue
                b1.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);



            }

            else if(array[i] == 2){
                //SEt button to Yellow
                b2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF00);


            }


            else if(array[i] == 3){
                //SEt button to Red
                b3.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);


            }


            else if(array[i] == 4){
                //SEt button to Green
                b4.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);


            }

            b1bool = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a bool to stop the for loop, and at the moment continuing the for loop by pressing button1:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:

        b1.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        b2.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        b3.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        b4.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        b1bool=false;
        ii++;
        play();



        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        if(b2bool == true)
        {


        }

        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        if(b3bool == true)
        {


        }

        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        if(b4bool == true)
        {


        }

        break;
    }   
}
```

I come to Stackoverflow because my usual way to solve programming problems are usually very long winding and not efficient at all, I need you experienced programmers advice on how to tackle the problem, when you give me a solution, or part of a solution I want to know how you arrived there so I can learn a better approach than I have now.

I was thinking of creating a method for each of the 50 levels and in there code to run each level, and call this in a for loop 50 times, this is not a good solution, but so far the only way I can think of doing this. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State machines like this can result in meandering code and I believe this is what you are seeing.

Consider removing the loop and instead trigger your 'play' code using the user/system input events: Button presses and the activity's life-cycle callbacks. You will be able to remove all the flag checking code.

Additionally, consider implementing each 'instruction' and 'correct input' using separate classes - Object Orientation. This will allow your code to be more scalable, while restricting the code inflation from adding new interactions. You can see if your example's that the switch statement takes up many lines. Imagine just having to iterate over a collection of 'responses' until you find a match for the action made by the user.

[image]

You will note the lack of code examples provided. As a learning experience, the implementation of my suggestions is a neat experiment and examples may limit the lessons taught.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I read it and spent a good amount of time trying to draw out a way to do this but I am kind of lost. The thing is though your answer makes perfect sense, I can see in my head why doing it this way would be the best way, I just lack the experience to do it so far. Thank you!!

Comment: I've edited my answer with a small diagram that amy give more clarity

Comment: Thank you, you provided me with what I asked for, advice on how to design and develop my application! I will use this as my basis!